# Analyze sensu log with logstash

Tags: filter, logstash, sensu

Here is my sensu log in the server:

```
{"timestamp":"2015-01-21T09:43:21.387501+0700","level":"info","message":"publishing check result","payload":{"client":"local.com","check":{"name":"instance_xxx_check","issued":1421808200,"command":"xargs -I{} sh -c '/opt/sensu/embedded/bin/ruby /etc/sensu/plugins/check-http.rb -u {}' < /etc/sensu/conf.d/live/list/xxx.txt","handlers":["default","mailer"],"interval":60,"subscribers":["live"],"executed":1421808200,"duration":1.317,"output":"CheckHTTP OK: 200, http://link1.com\nCheckHTTP CRITICAL: Request error: http://link2.com\nCheckHTTP OK: 200, http://link3.com\n","status":123}}}
```

this is in json format, you can use json parse to view it.

And after pass logstash filter, it will parse in fields like this image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KA0i.jpg

And now I want to add a field named "error" which just contain information of critical "http://link.com". It's mean, if filter match CheckHTTP CRITICAL in the "payload.check.output" field, it'll add the error link to new "error" field

And this is my config in logstash filter:

```
if [type] == "sensu" {
            grok {
                match => [ "payload.check.output", "%{CISCO_REASON}: Request error: %{URI}" ]
            }
            mutate {
                add_field => { "error" => "%{payload.check.output}" }
                remove_field => [ "timestamp" ]
            }
        }
```

but there is nothing happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use this config to access the nested json message.

```
input {
    stdin{}
}

filter {
    json {
            source => "message"
    }
    if [payload][check][output] =~ /CheckHTTP CRITICAL/
    {
        ruby
        {
            code => "
                errormsg = '';
                msg = event['payload']['check']['output'];
                splitmsg = msg.split(/\n/)
                for splitlog in splitmsg
                     if splitlog.include? 'CheckHTTP CRITICAL'
                         errormsg = errormsg + splitlog.split('error: ')[1];
                     end
                end
                event['error'] = errormsg
            "
        }
    }
}


output {
    stdout {
            codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

The above config can parse out the error link and insert to `error` field.

If you found that your requirement is hard to implemented by logstash plugin, you can try to use `ruby` filter to code it yourself. So, for the next time you can try it yourself. Enjoy it.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank you, Ben Lim but it display all 3 link in Error field (and I've try this config), my goal is to split it, error field just contain a single error link. Because it just happen error in 1 link and 2 link remain are ok in sometime

http://i.imgur.com/uFnzxb0.jpg
3 links are displayed

Comment: Hi, Jin. I have updated the answer. Please have a try on it again. I think it can answer your question.